Simplified explanation of how Earth's climate changed cyclically over the past 2 million years?
I am interested in the Homo lineage, starting around the 2mya mark, and wondering how the climate changed over those past 2 million years. I just asked on the Astronomy SE Elaborating how the 3 cycles of the Milankovitch cycles work (405k years, 95k years, and 124k years)? to better understand these astronomical cycles, and how they impact climate. But as per this answer (related question), CO2 levels and other things can also have a big impact on climate, so climate is more of an Earth Sciences thing that an astronomical thing, so wanted to clarify a few points here.
How can I keep track of in my head how the climate cycled through high levels of ice and low levels of ice? How do the cycles work roughly? How can I understand it in such a way as to explain it to a high-school educated group of people in simplified form?
Mainly, does the climate go through a predicable cycling pattern? Not exactly like a sine wave (high and low levels of ice are cycled through to the same levels), but maybe it is some sort of (predictable) superposition of sine waves or something like that (like these images)? (If not, what is it then???).





And what other factors contribute to the climate change, besides the Milankovitch cycles, the yearly cycle, and the CO2 levels?
